Labeling of classical triangle centers: Why $H$ for orthocenter, $G$ for centroid, $O$ for circumcenter?
I was learning about triangles, and I came to know that orthocenter is represented by $H$, centroid is represented by $G$, and circumcenter is represented by $O$.
I don't understand why these are named using these specific letters only. Can anyone please tell the reason?
Shouldn't the circumcenter be $C$ and orthocenter be $O$ because they are the first letters and it would be easy to remember why $H$, $G$, $O$?

This might be a good question for History of Science and Math.SE (but it's not really off-topic here).

Fun Fact: Google's AI responds: The letter "H" is typically used to denote the orthocenter of a triangle because it stands for "orthocenter" itself [...]; essentially, "H" is the initial letter of "orthocenter" [...]. An object lesson in not trusting AI for math questions (or even spelling questions, for that matter). :)

The centroid is the center of Gravity. And $C$ would be a terrible name since the vertices of the triangle are $A$, $B$, $C$.

$H$ is the point where the altitudes intersects. It's usual to call the lengths of the altitudes $h_A$, $h_B$ and $h_C$ because this are the Heights of the triangle.

$O$ is in general a common name for the center of any circle. So in particular, in the context of the triangle centers it's quite natural to call $O$ to the center of the circumcircle.
